# Evaluating an indeterminate form of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

we got the question as:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x }{x}
$$
Now note here that $x$ denotes the greatest integer function; so clearly De L'Hospital's Rule cannot be applied here directly, as when approaching:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]
$$
and when from the other side it's:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin x }{x}=\frac{\sin (-1) }{-1}
$$
But i think my approach is not correct, how do I evaluate this correctly?

Comment: I don't understand: are you trying to evaluate the limit of $\;\frac{\sin x}x\;$ or of $\;\lfloor\frac{\sin x}x\rfloor\;$ ? Because if it is the latter the sign of floor function doesn't appear around $\;\frac{\sin x}x\;$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right hand limit does not exist, because the function is not defined in $[0,1)$.  The left hand limit will be

$$\frac{\sin (-1)}{-1}=\sin(1)$$

as you've written.  A two-sided limit exists if and only if both one-sided limits exist and are equal.  Here we see that these conditions do not hold, so the original limit does not exist.